# Почему код в 1 и во 2 случаях выдает разный результат?

Tags: javascript, функции, дата

Вообще код должен выдавать в качестве результата `ПТ` - 3 января 2014 года это пятница. Но мне не совсем понятно почему мой код выдает такие результаты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function getWeekDay(date) {
    let days = ['ВС', 'ПН', 'ВТ', 'СР', 'ЧТ', 'ПТ', 'СБ'];
    return days[date.getDate()];
}
let date2 = new Date(2014, 0, 3);  
console.log(getWeekDay(date2)); //ПТ

function getWeekDay(date) {
  let days = ['ВС', 'ПН', 'ВТ', 'СР', 'ЧТ', 'ПТ', 'СБ'];
  return days[date.getDay()];
}
let date = new Date(2014, 0, 3); 
console.log( getWeekDay(date) ); //ПТ
```

```js
function getWeekDay(date) {
    let days = ['ВС', 'ПН', 'ВТ', 'СР', 'ЧТ', 'ПТ', 'СБ'];
    return days[date.getDate()];
}
let date2 = new Date(2014, 0, 3);  
console.log(getWeekDay(date2)); //СР
```

В первом случае код выдает `ПТ`, но во втором случае - `СР`. Как так получается? Почему в первом случае не выдает `CР`?

Comment: очевидно, что getDay и getDate дают разные резльтат..... отсюда и разница........а что именно они возвращают - достаточно посмотреть в документацию

Comment: в первом случае вторая функция перезатирает первую с таким же именем......вроде бы тоже очевидно........ надеюсь вы не надеялись, что 1000 функций с одинаковым именем можно расположить на странице?